# How to change original variable

Tags: python

I am trying to change `variable` using `new_variable`

```py
variable = 10
new_variable = variable
new_variable += 1
print(new_variable) 
print(variable)
```

I see that `new_variable` has changed while `variable` has not.
Is there a way to modify the value of `variable` using `new_variable`?

Comment: From your code, variable is not suppose to change. What do you expect?

Comment: Python readds form left to right, so you need to write at the end before print: `variable = new_variable`

Comment: In your code you set new_variable to have the same value as variable at the exact point in time when `new_variable = variable` is executed. This does not mean they are the same thing from there on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class objects to get this behaviour.

```
class num:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n = n
variable= num(5)
newvariable = variable
newvariable.n = 3
print(variable.n)
print(newvariable.n)
```

Or you can use lists for the same

```
variable= [5]
newvariable = variable
newvariable[0] = 3
print(variable[0])
print(newvariable[0])
```

OUTPUT

```
3
3
```